# is the isp gateway ip ONLY bind on 1 device?

Tags: router, ip, port-forwarding, isp, gateway

My case, I have a router (with isp that change gateway ip regulary), a client on that router (raspi) and other device with internet outside router network (android phone).

I get isp gateway ip 10.196.80.165 (checked on router), get external ip 114.142.170.44 (checked on raspi) and have port forwarding router to raspi that run apache with setting : port 1234 to 192.168.1.101 port 80 (local ip raspi).

when I go to 10.196.80.165:1234 on my phone that's show me raspi apache server (I can access my web hosted by my raspi from outside network).

my question is :
1. is the isp gateway ip ONLY bind on 1 device? (I mean 10.196.80.165 only belongs to my router not other people router)
2. is my raspi is vulnerable if I use this method?

note : I set static ip 192.168.1.101 to raspi from router by mac address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but if I understand it correctly yes. In fact, its more specific - a world-routable address only binds to 1 interface on 1 device. (And typically you get 1 IP from your ISP and use NAT - ie network address translation - to have multiple systems usec1 address)

It sounds like you are wanting to reach a web server in your LAN while outside. In order to do this you set up port forwarding on your router. It is possible to reach many devices behind your router by routing requests to different ports - although this will make the URLs less memorable as you need to specify the port in the URL if you are not using the assigned port.

Comment: it's true that I want to reach my local web server from outside. https://kb.netgear.com/23944/I-have-a-Nighthawk-router-what-is-Dynamic-DNS-and-why-should-I-set-up-a-free-Dynamic-DNS-account write "If your ISP assigns a private WAN IP address (such as 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x), the Dynamic DNS service does not work because private addresses are not routed on the Internet". My router ip is 10.196.80.165 so I can't use ddns. Depends on your answer, I assume that 10.196.80.165 is only bind on my router on that time. And what about question number 2.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Your router has at least 2 IPs assigned to it. What IP addresses are associated with your routers LAN, WAN and any other Interface. (If your ISP has assigned your router a 10.x WAN address and you are not using PPP or similar they are incompetent/not a real ISP).If your WAN IP address starts 10.x.x.x your ISP is using NAT - and indeed that IP address can exist in multiple places and is not routable, so you can't run a world reachable webserver without additional/changed connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now I realize that I missunderstood something. I just want to access my raspi remotely with private WAN ip. Are you have some advice? Or subscribe on isp that provide public/static ip is the only way?

Comment: You will need a public IP address.   If you don't want to change ISP you can set up a VPN (or a tunnel), but you need to make sure that the VPN provider allocates you your own IP address, because you are not wanting the service for anonymity, rather to get a virtual interface on your system with a world reachable IP address.   Google "VPN static IP" for a list of providers.  This service is likely to cost between US$2 and US$10 per month. (You could role your own using AWS or similar as well, but its a lot of work, and likely more expensive in the long run)